# My python paho-mqtt consumer client stops receiving data

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a MQTT consumer receiving data from a publisher client publishing every 15 minutes.
I use the Mosquitto broker.

My consumer client can sometimes run for days without problems and sometimes it only takes a couple of hours. Eventually it stops receiving data without leaving any traces in the log file.

Do I use it in a wrong way or am I missing something.

If I restart the service the problem is gone until next time.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class BFproxy:
    def postdata(self,name,sg,t):
        ....
        return r

class MQTTConsumer:
    def __init__(self,bfproxy):
        self.bfproxy=bfproxy
        self.channel=conf["MQTT"]["channel"]+"#"
        print(f"HER {self.channel}")
        log.info(f"MQTT running trying to subscripe to {self.channel}")
        self.run_mqtt()

    def run_mqtt(self):
            self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client("clientname",1,False)
            self.mqtt_client.on_message = self.recieve_mqtt_message
            self.mqtt_client.connect(conf['MQTT']['IP'])
            
            self.mqtt_client.subscribe(self.channel)   
            if conf["LOG"]["MQTT"] == "YES":
                self.mqtt_client.enable_logger()
            self.mqtt_client.loop_forever()
            

    def on_mqtt_disconnect(self,client,userdata,rc):
        logging.error(f"MQTT disconnects")
        self.mqtt_client.reconnect()
        self.mqtt_client.subscribe(self.channel)
        if conf["LOG"]["MQTT"] == "YES":
            self.mqtt_client.enable_logger()
        self.mqtt_client.loop_start()
        log.info("MQTT running again")

    def recieve_mqtt_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        msg_dict = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        log.debug(f"MQTT: {message.topic} - {msg_dict}")
        r=self.bfproxy.postdata(...)

def main():
    bf=BFproxy()
    mc=MQTTConsumer(bf)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

LOG form MOSQUITTO:

```
1616598279: New connection from 192.168.1.95 on port 1883.
1616598279: New client connected from 192.168.1.95 as brewfatherMQTT (c1, k60).
1616598279: No will message specified.
1616598279: Sending CONNACK to brewfatherMQTT (0, 0)
1616598279: Received SUBSCRIBE from brewfatherMQTT
1616598279:     smarthome/tilt/# (QoS 0)
1616598279: brewfatherMQTT 0 smarthome/tilt/#
1616598279: Sending SUBACK to brewfatherMQTT
1616598279: Sending PUBLISH to brewfatherMQTT (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'smarthome/tilt', ... (296 bytes))

1616598340: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616598340: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT

1616603764: New connection from 192.168.1.95 on port 1883.
1616603764: New client connected from 192.168.1.95 as tilt2mqtt.py (c1, k60).
1616603764: No will message specified.
1616603764: Sending CONNACK to tilt2mqtt.py (0, 0)
1616603764: Received PUBLISH from tilt2mqtt.py (d0, q1, r1, m6, 'smarthome/tilt', ... (296 bytes))
1616603764: Sending PUBACK to tilt2mqtt.py (Mid: 6)
1616603764: Sending PUBLISH to brewfatherMQTT (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'smarthome/tilt', ... (296 bytes))
1616603764: Received DISCONNECT from tilt2mqtt.py
1616603764: Client tilt2mqtt.py disconnected.
1616603767: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616603767: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT

1616604189: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616604189: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT
1616604249: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616604249: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT
1616604340: Client brewfatherMQTT has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1616604340: Socket error on client brewfatherMQTT, disconnecting.

1616604458: Sending CONNACK to brewfatherMQTT (0, 0)
1616604519: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616604519: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT

1616604667: New connection from 192.168.1.95 on port 1883.
1616604667: New client connected from 192.168.1.95 as tilt2mqtt.py (c1, k60).
1616604667: No will message specified.
1616604667: Sending CONNACK to tilt2mqtt.py (0, 0)
1616604667: Received PUBLISH from tilt2mqtt.py (d0, q1, r1, m7, 'smarthome/tilt', ... (296 bytes))
1616604667: Sending PUBACK to tilt2mqtt.py (Mid: 7)
############### NO PUBLISH TO brewfatherMQTT ###############################
1616604667: Received DISCONNECT from tilt2mqtt.py
1616604667: Client tilt2mqtt.py disconnected.

1616604701: Received PINGREQ from brewfatherMQTT
1616604701: Sending PINGRESP to brewfatherMQTT
```

Comment: And you've 1) checked the broker logs? 2) checked that that messages are still getting published?

Comment: 1616604340: Client brewfatherMQTT has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1616604340: Socket error on client brewfatherMQTT, disconnecting.

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using and what happens if you also run `mosquitto_sub` at the same time?

Comment: Good point. Actually version 1.5.7. I will try a newer version.